# Is this 1st or 2nd order logic?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm reading "Set Theory and the Continuum Problem" by Smullyan & Fitting, and on page 16 it says:

> Thus, we allow $\forall x$ for $x$ a set variable, but not $\forall A$ for $A$ a class variable.

But right below that it states:

> $P_2$ Separation
>
> $$(\forall A_1)\ldots(\forall A_n)(\exists B)(\forall c)[x \in B \iff \phi(A_1,\ldots,A_n)]$$
>
> Intuitively, each axiom $P_2$ says that given any subclasses $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of $V$ there...

So I'm confused. Why isn't this quantifying over class variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first quote is regarding the definition of a first-order property, not a universal prohibition. The sentences of the axiom schema are not first-order sentences in this sense, but the formulas $\varphi$ that the schema ranges order are all the first-order formulas.

So in other words, what they mean is that for each formula of the form $\varphi(A_1,\ldots, A_n, x)$ that does not include any class quantifiers, $$ \forall A_1\ldots \forall A_n\exists B\forall x(x\in B\iff \varphi(A_1,\ldots, A_n,x))$$ is an axiom. (Note that they should have also stipulated that $\varphi$ does not contain the variable $B$.)

---

On the general question of "is this first or second-order logic?", even though we talk about class variables as "2nd-order variables" as the classes over which they range are informally collections of sets, NBG is a first-order theory. One can either consider it as a two-sorted first-order theory, or a one-sorted theory where sets are a special type of class (I can't tell which one the authors are using as they are being pretty informal about it).

What gives away that it's first-order isn't that the separation schema ranges over first-order predicates, but that it's a schema... in a full-on second-order theory, we would be able to quantify over "all properties", and we wouldn't need a separation schema. (Morse-Kelley is a stronger theory that allows all formulas in its separation schema, but is still considered first order.)

Sometimes people do say it is second-order theory, but emphasize that [Henkin semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_logic#Semantics) is intended. (But then, it's common to call Henkin semantics "first-order semantics for second-order languages.") This is sort of like how in [reverse mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_mathematics) you see the words "second-order arithmetic" all the time, but the theories of study really are using Henkin semantics or are first-order theories, depending on how you look at it. In fact, the relationship between ACA$_0$ and PA bears several similarities to the relationship between NBG and ZFC. ("Arithmetical comprehension" is analogous to "first-order separation".)

Comment: The authors call $V$ the universal class of all sets: with "sets" being the elements of $V$ and "classes" be the subcollections of $V$. However, the first axiom is that every set is a class. Still, I thought that $V$ was the domain of discourse so that quantification had to be over sets, but I guess that was my incorrect assumption and the domain of discourse are the classes.

Comment: When you wrote "what they mean is each formula of the form $\varphi(A_1,\ldots, A_n, x)$ that does not include any class quantifiers...," are you saying that's what the axiom schema should be, or that's how you interpret what they wrote? Because to me the phrase "given any subclasses $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ of $V$" indicates that those are class variables that are being quantified over. I don't see any statement in that passage that restricts those variables to being sets.

Comment: Then again, I suppose it doesn't make any sense to have an axiom that says that all sets are classes if classes are the domain of discourse, because if sets weren't in the domain of discourse then you couldn't have axioms that quantify over them. So I'm not sure what the authors are doing. Intuitively I feel like I get what they're saying, but trying to understand the formal logic is hard without knowing the exact domain of discourse, and having the axioms in natural language.

Comment: @Joe $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ are being quantified over when stating the instance of separation. They are not being quantified over in $\varphi$... they are free in $\varphi.$ The point is that $\varphi$ can't be something like $\exists D\;(x\in D\lor x\in A_1)$... plugging that into the schema isn't a valid instance of separation, whereas letting $\varphi$ be $\exists y(x\in y\lor x\in A)$ would result in a valid instance. (Also on a side note, something that both I and the authors forgot to mention: $B$ cannot occur in $\varphi$.)

Comment: @Joe The way I think of it is that the domain of discourse is the classes, and then the sets are special kinds of classes that are elements of other classes... they can be distinguished formally by the predicate $Set(B):=\exists A\;B\in A$, there is a name $V$ for the universal class, defined by extensionality as $B\in V\iff Set(B)$, and then set quantifiers $\forall x\varphi(x)$ and $\exists x\varphi(x)$ are abbreviations for $\forall A(A\in V\to \varphi(A))$ and $\exists A( A\in V\land \varphi(A)).$ (But as I mentioned in the answer, you can also think of it as a two-sorted domain.)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I don't know the difference between "quantified over when stating the instance of separation" and "quantified over in $\phi$." I just finished [An Introduction to Formal Logic](https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl/), and I only remember quantifying over the domain of discourse.  Your way of thinking about the domain of discourse makes sense to me, but I don't think that's what the authors are doing. If it is, then I don't understand having axiom 1 state "Every set is a class." I hope I can think of it your way without contradicting the authors' presentation.

Comment: @Joe I agree they seem to not be doing it that way and instead be using two-sorted first-order logic (if anything can be distilled from their very informal approach). But that's not that hard to adapt to from having only learned one-sorted logic... instead of one domain, you have two domains, classes and sets, and one type of quantifier/variable ranges over the classes and the other ranges over the sets.

Comment: @Joe The difference is that $\phi$ is not the separation axiom instance itself, but a subformula of it. It is that subformula that is required to not contain any class quantifiers, not the axiom itself, which manifestly contains class quantifiers. e.g. $\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\iff \exists y(x\in y\land x\in A))$ is an instance of the separation axiom, but $\forall A\exists B\forall x(x\in B\iff \exists C(x\in C\land x\in A))$ is not.

Comment: I see your distinction, but I guess I don't understand why we're allowed to quantify over classes for axioms, but only over sets for subformulas. So far, my weak understanding of FOL vs SOL is that FOL only quantifies over the domain of discourse, but SOL can also quantify over predicates. So I'm under the impression that it matters what you quantify over, but I haven't read about it mattering where you quantify (whole axiom vs subformula). You've given me a good place to start trying to learn more. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe We're allowed to quantify over classes whenever/whereever we want. The issue is what constitutes an instance of the separation axiom. (As for why that is the rule, I don't personally believe there is a compelling philosophical justification for it over Morse-Kelley where you allow any formula. It does happen to make NBG finitely axiomatizable and conservative over ZFC, unlike MK, which can be useful in certain contexts.)

Comment: Oh, ok, so if I understand you correctly, NBG is a first order theory, but the separation axioms require $\phi$ to be a "first order property", which is a distinct concept, and which means that $\phi$ can be defined in terms of a subformula that quantifies over sets, but it is not allowed to quantify over classes. And I believe you are saying that has nothing to do with whether it is FOL or SOL (it is FOL), but is just a choice of axioms which happens to make NBG finitely axiomatizable and conservative over ZFC.

Comment: @Joe Yes. that's right.

Comment: Great, thank you!